# How to import just a single constant or function from a library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a script that uses a single constant from the library string. Instead of importing the whole library, which seems like overkill, can I import just this constant? Is there more than one way?

I tried

```
from string import ascii_letters
```

which worked when I also fixed the name in my code (`string.ascii_letters` became `ascii_letters`). I would also like to import just a single function from the library `random`. My experiments just game me syntax errors. Is this possible, or do I need the whole library/module to get the functions in it? I couldn't find the answer in the documentation for the import system.

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? Are you looking for `from library import constant`?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, which I figured out (sorry for posting before experimenting), but which raised another question; see edited question! Thank you.

Comment: If you're asking about code that has an error, *give a [mcve]*.

Comment: @Scivias: If you used the `from x import y` syntax correctly, it wouldn't give errors (unless you named a file `random.py` in the current directory, shadowing the built-in, and your own `random.py` has syntax errors). *What* error did you get? "syntax errors" without the line that triggered it is useless. Mind you, this won't actually improve module load efficiency; to get a single value from the module, it still loads and caches the whole module in memory, you're just importing a few specific names from said cache.

Comment: Thanks, ShadowRanger, since efficiency was my goal, it's good to know that this won't improve it. Just for info, the error was from `from random import randint()` - "invalid syntax" popup highlighted the ( and adding arguments inside the () did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax errors you mentioned are either in the script you import to or the module itself.
If it's in the module, we have to see it to know whats wrong, but I'll assume you've tested that mod.
That leaves us with your current script. The Line `import name`, long as name exists (locally), would not trigger syntax errors. same with the format

```
from name import something
```

This makes me think that your problem is somewhere else, and if you can add you code then it might be possible to help. (to clarify - importing just one const, function, etc. *will not* triggera syntax error, given you have typed the right names).